# Jenkins slave went offline because of SSH issue

Tags: jenkins

Our Jenkins master/slave setup suddenly stopped working. Both master and slave are AWS ec2 machines and we have a user called jenkins. We are seeing this error:

> [07/17/19 14:58:04] [SSH] Opening SSH connection to 10.xx.xxx.xxx:22. [07/17/19 14:58:04] [SSH] WARNING: SSH Host Keys are not being verified. Man-in-the-middle attacks may be possible against this connection.
>
> [07/17/19 14:58:04] [SSH] Authentication successful. SSH connection reports a garbage before a command execution. Check your .bashrc, .profile, and so on to make sure it is quiet.
> The received junk text is as follows: WARNING: Your password has expired. Password change required but no TTY available.

I have checked the .bashrc and .profile files on both machines and they have not changed since a long time. Our authentication method is "SSH Username with private key" and private key looks fine. Nothing has changed on our side. Has anyone else faced this issue?

Comment: Did you read the "received junk text"? It seems pretty obvious about what the problem is.

Comment: So, I need to check password of the jenkins user? What do I need to do if I don't know the current password of that user and I can't change the password?

Comment: The root user can change any user's password, or remove the password expiration time. So you use `sudo`.

Comment: I tried "passwd jenkins" as root and I get this error:

passwd jenkins
passwd: avc.c:74: avc_context_to_sid_raw: Assertion `avc_running' failed.
Aborted

Comment: Your system has bigger problems than just an expired password, then. You most likely failed to install an update for `selinux-policy` or some similar package.

Comment: I already answered this question when you cross-posted it to SU: https://superuser.com/questions/1460917/jenkins-slave-agent-goes-offline-seeing-ssh-errors

Comment: Thanks! We had resolved the issue by creating a new user and making its password as non-expiring and connected master and slave by generating new key for that user.